# Live Digital clock with timezones

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a digital clock that is running and it works great but I want to have multiple clocks running with different timezones.  I am on the west coast and I would like the time to be different when people look at it in different timezones.  How can I accomplish this?

```
function displayTime() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        var meridiem = "AM";  

        if (hours > 12) {
            hours = hours - 12; 
            meridiem = "PM"; 
        }

        if (hours === 0) {
            hours = 12;
        }

        if(hours < 10) {

            hours = "0" + hours;
        }

        if(minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if(seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        var clockDiv = document.getElementById('clock');

        clockDiv.innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridiem;
    }

    displayTime();

    setInterval(displayTime, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Do you care about accuracy? If you do, don't use the browser's time, use your server's time.

Comment: hmmm may i ask how i do that?  Yes accuracy is important

Comment: For noon, this will show 12 AM when it is convention to show 12 PM. By default, this will show the time based on the host system settings (i.e. "local" time). If you want to show the time in a particular time zone, then adjust the UTC values (e.g. using setUTCMinutes) by the required offset and use UTC methods (getUTCMinutes, etc.) to format the date string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the time in any timezone based on the current system time (which might be wrong, but that may not really matter), create a Date and just adjust the UTC time values by the required offset, then use UTC methods to build your formatted string.

e.g.

```js
/*  Return a time string in h:m:s a/p format
**
**  @param {number} offsetInMinutes - offset of required timezone in minutes
**  @returns {string} formatted time string
*/
function getTimeInZone(offsetInMinutes) {
  function z(n) {return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
  var d = new Date();
  d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() + offsetInMinutes);
  var h = d.getUTCHours();
  return z(h%12||12) + ':' + z(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' +
         z(d.getUTCSeconds()) + ' ' + (h<12? 'am' : 'pm');
}

// Time at UTC-08:00
document.write(getTimeInZone(-480));
```

You say you're "on the west coast", but not of where, so I'll assume USA where the likely timezone offset is UTC-08:00 (-480 minutes). So to always show the time in that timezone (with the usual caveat that the system clock may not be correct), you'd do:

```
getTimeInZone(-480);
```

Also note that *innerText* is a IE proprietary property and not supported in all browsers.